# Java OpenGL rotate text from center point

Tags: java, opengl, text, rotation, jogl

I am trying to rotate a text using JOGL but it does not rotate from the center point. What can I do with the following code to rotate from the center of the text?

```
TextRenderer textRenderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 20));

textRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
textRenderer.beginRendering(viewport.width, viewport.height, false);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPushMatrix();

gl.glTranslated(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, 0);
gl.glRotated(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
gl.glTranslated(-screenPoint.x, -screenPoint.y, 0);

textRenderer.draw("Text", (int) screenPoint.x, (int) screenPoint.y);
textRenderer.endRendering();
gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPopMatrix();
textRenderer.flush();
```

Comment: Which point is the center of the text? What is the size of the text?

Comment: Size is 20 as you may see it from the first line of the code. Center of the text is the center of the String i.e. "This is the text". But if you ask the center based on the screen, then screenPoint.x and screenPoint.y are the center pivot points for rotation.

Comment: If `screenPoint` would be the center of the text, then your code would work.

Comment: As I know in OpenGL screenpoint is always the left bottom of the text. But I need to find the center and rotate based on the center.

Comment: So why do you say *"screenPoint.x and screenPoint.y are the center pivot points for rotation"*?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Probably you need to draw the text at a different position: `textRenderer.draw("Text", (int)(screenPoint.x - textWidth/2.0), (int)(screenPoint.y - textHeight/2.0));`